# quote.shippingAddress() is getting null/with no values , just after adding new billing address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, billing-address

quote.shippingAddress() gets blank/with no values in object , while adding to new billing address
in Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer  in initObservable() method in default.js file.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented this portion of code solves issue

```
initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function () {
            checkoutDataResolver.resolveBillingAddress();
        }, this);

      /*  shippingRatesValidator.initFields(this.get('name') + '.form-fields'); */
    },
```